# Where to change prefetch value in activemq

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I read documentation about `prefetch buffer`.As per my understanding If I assign `Prefetch` value =1 to consumer A. Activemq push 1 message at a time to A .once A sends acknowledgement to activemq,then only activemq push another message to A.

My doubt was,where I need to assign prefetch value to consumer.

Am I need to assign prefetch value in consumer program.If it is right,can you explain with simple code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

As per the [ActiveMQ manual](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html):

> ActiveMQ uses a **prefetch limit** on how many messages can be streamed to
>   a consumer at any point in time. Once the prefetch limit is reached,
>   no more messages are dispatched to the consumer until the consumer
>   starts sending back acknowledgements of messages (to indicate that the
>   message has been processed). The actual prefetch limit value can be
>   specified on a per consumer basis.

**To change the prefetch size for all consumer types you would use a connection URI similar to:**

```
tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=50
```

**To change the prefetch size for just queue consumer types you would use a connection URI similar to:**

```
tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1
```

**It can also be configured on a per consumer basis using Destination Options.**

```
queue = new ActiveMQQueue("TEST.QUEUE?consumer.prefetchSize=10");
consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From yesterday onwards,I am trying one task clearly I explained in the following [link]  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630657/how-to-push-messages-from-activemq-to-consumer) . can you check it once.

Answer (score 3):

Though it is old thread.

If you are using spring with ActiveMQ integration

```
<!-- A connection to ActiveMQ -->
    <bean id="orderStatusAmqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL">
         <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" /> 
         <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true" /> 
         <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
         <property name="trustedPackages">
        <list>
            <value>com.myapp.tradingplatform</value>
            <value>java</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
    <property name="queuePrefetch" value="1000" />
</bean>
    <!-- A cached connection to wrap the ActiveMQ connection -->
    <bean id="orderStatusCachedConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
            <ref bean="orderStatusAmqConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize">
            <value>100</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```